# MySQL trigger to insert records from Table A to Table B

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am unable to get the following code to work, using this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) for reference as well as of other posts on this site. I need to create a trigger that will insert a record in Table B whenever Table A is updated. The code below shows what I am attempting; however this produces a syntax error (#1064). I am also unclear on if I need to include the 'DELIMITER $$' syntax or not. I appreciate your help

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
AFTER INSERT
ON TableA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableB SET 
    TableA_id = NEW.TableB_id, 
    TableA_date = NEW.TableB_date,
    TableA_comment = NEW.TableB_comment;
  END;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT**: in the pseudo-code above I am using a $TableName_$FieldName convention to indicate that Column A belongs to Table A, Column B belongs to Table B. I should have made that more clear in my original question. Someone commented below I have the NEW indicator on the wrong side (should be on Table A), but that comment appears to have been removed. Can someone please confirm? Thanks for all your help

Comment: In reply to your edit: are you saying that in `TableB` you *don't* have a column called `TableA_id`, but instead you want to insert a row into `TableB` such that the value of `TableB.TableB_id` is equal to the value of `TableA.TableA_id` etc?

Comment: @eggyal TableB consists of TableB_id, TableB_date, and TableB_comment; likewise for Tabel A. Sorry for not making that more clear in my original question. I basically want to insert the same record into Table B when Table A gets updated

Comment: In that case, you do indeed need to reverse the column names in your `INSERT` statement, e.g. `SET TableB_id = NEW.TableA_id` etc.

Comment: Ah-ah! I was right then, even if by pure luck, and the assignment WAS actually reversed.

Comment: Edited my answer after your clarification about field names.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: Indeed.  My apologies for jumping to conclusions!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
AFTER INSERT
ON TableA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableB SET 
    TableB_id = NEW.TableA_id, 
    TableB_date = NEW.TableA_date,
    TableB_comment = NEW.TableA_comment;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The `DELIMITER` here is used to tell mysql to treat all the following `;` as part of the definition instead of actual command terminations.

Notice that I removed an unmatched `END;` just before the closing `END $$`

Comment: How do you know the column names in `TableB`?

Comment: What does this mean? He has to now the column names while writing the query, but if he wants to use the UPDATE-like sintax for insert, on the left side he must have the column name of TableB and in that place he puts the value he wants from the NEWly insert row of TableA. I really do not understand your downvote, it make no sense to me!

Comment: I mean, you've changed the column names to something other than what the OP had.  How do you know better than him what are the names of the columns in his tables?  In any event, this would not explain a #1064 syntax error.  However, since you have removed the erroneous `END;`, your answer does now hint at a solution to the problem and I have removed my downvote.  That said, your commentary "*I think you're doing the insert in the wrong fields*" diverts attention from the actual problem, and your trigger probably won't work until the column names are reverted.

Comment: I see now what do you mean, but still, wouldn't it be wrong trying to do an insert on a TableA field during the triggered insert on TableB, as @Arkady seems to be doing in his query?

Comment: Oh, I see it now! How dumb of me... Edited the answer, should be clearer now.

Comment: OP = Original Poster.  And I suspect, although I might well be wrong, that `TableA_id` etc. are indeed the names of columns in `TableB`. For example, imagine `TableA` and `TableB` were called `Owners` and `Cars` respectively: in `Cars` one might well have a column called `Owner_id`.

Comment: I agree with your revised answer - it is, after all, the same as mine! ;)  +1

Answer (score 1):

You have an erroneous `END;` in your trigger (every `END` should pair with a `BEGIN`).

For that matter, you don't even need the `BEGIN ... END` block, since the trigger contains only one statement (and if that block is omitted, you don't even need to change the statement delimiter because no semicolon appears *within* the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement):

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger AFTER INSERT ON TableA FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO TableB SET 
    TableA_id = NEW.TableB_id, 
    TableA_date = NEW.TableB_date,
    TableA_comment = NEW.TableB_comment
```